# OpenLayers 'Canvas area exceeds the maximum limit' error in WKWebView

Tags: openlayers, javascript, error

I'm using OpenLayers 6.13 in an iOS app.  The app also runs on macOS (Mac Catalyst).  The OpenLayers component runs in a WKWebView (essentially a Safari-esque web browser view, embedded in the app).

When running on the Mac if I increase the size of the window, the vector layers disappear and the javascript console reports the error:

`Canvas area exceeds the maximum limit (width * height > 16777216).`

If I decrease the window size again, the layers re-appear on the map.

(The WMTS layers never disappear, even when the window is larger.)

What's very odd about this, is that I can get the same layers to run in a very similar actual web site in actual Safari in the same map in a much larger browser window.  The problem only seems to exist in my WKWebView.

How can this error be avoided in larger windows with OpenLayers?

Comment: If the problem to due to a very high resolution device you could set the pixelRatio option in the map constructor.  Otherwise try v6.15 or later there were some efforts made to reduce canvas use https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.15.0

Comment: Thanks @Mike , v6.15.1 did not help, but changing the map's 'pixelRatio' to 1.0 did resolve it.  I think that this is going to be the solution for me for now.  If you write it up as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it correct (otherwise, I will do so later).